# Adding OnClickListener to a listview which is added to XML like "@android:id"

Tags: android, onclick, listener

My problem is that I cannot reach ListView in Java. I'm using a ListActivity. In XML layout, I have a listview but I added it like `android:id="@android:id/list`

When I try to reach that list with code `findViewById(R.id.list)` ... I does not work because it is not my namespace's view. 
I need to add clicklistener to my view which is added like "@android:id".
My Java part :

```
 mailList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
```

My XML Part:

```
<ListView  android:layout_height="400dp" 
           android:id="@android:id/list" 
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"></ListView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the list id from the Android resources class like this:

```
android.R.id.list
```